# How do I use file as input stream to existing C++ program?

Tags: c++, shell

I have a existing program and I can't modify it. It use `std::cin` to read user's input.

Now I don't want to type in it every time, so I create a file like this:

```
3
2 2
3 4
5 1
```

How do I use this file as input stream ? I'm using OS X.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the bash (or similar) shell and your input is in the file `input.in` then

```
myprogram < input.in
```

Will use input.in as the standard input to the program.